# cannot upload a file in javascript using php

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, file

I am trying to upload a file using php. But the following error is generated. `Error: A problem occurred during file upload!` . I am using ubuntu OS. I think the error is generated while trying to save that file. 
I used the following code

```
<html>
<body>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
    Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploaded_file" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>


<?php
//Сheck that we have a file
if((!empty($_FILES["uploaded_file"])) && ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0)) {
  //Check if the file is JPEG image and it's size is less than 350Kb
  $filename = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
  $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
  if (($ext == "jpg") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") && 
    ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] < 350000)) {
    //Determine the path to which we want to save this file
      $newname = dirname(__FILE__).'/upload/'.$filename;
      //Check if the file with the same name is already exists on the server
      if (!file_exists($newname)) {
        //Attempt to move the uploaded file to it's new place
        if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],$newname))) {
           echo "It's done! The file has been saved as: ".$newname;
        } else {
           echo "Error: A problem occurred during file upload!";
        }
      } else {
         echo "Error: File ".$_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]." already exists";
      }
  } else {
     echo "Error: Only .jpg images under 350Kb are accepted for upload";
  }
} else {
 echo "Error: No file uploaded";
}
?>
```

what is the problem of this code? or is this because of file permision to access the folder?

Comment: From PHP manual `Additionally, a warning will be issued.`. If you have the errors logged, please post them.

Comment: the $_FILES array will contain the error code

Comment: Most likely that you have a problem with permissions. Also, ensure that path `dirname(__FILE__).'/upload/` really exists. Plus - ensure that `dirname(__FILE__)` returns exactly what you expect from it.

Comment: there is no errors listed in firebug.

Comment: PHP has nothing common with Firebug.  `move_uploaded_file` works on server side and you should look for errors in php error log file. And firebug works with client side only. Of course, you may have FirePHP (or something like that) extension which may show errors from server.

Comment: is `upload` folder exist and writable ? for now, do `print_r($FILES['uploaded_file']['error'])` instead of echoing some msgs.

Comment: no errors in error.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find where an error occurs.

```
<?php

$msg = '';
$upload_key = 'uploaded_file';

if (isset($_FILES[$upload_key])) {

    try {

        $error = $_FILES[$upload_key]['error'];
        switch ($error) {
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                throw new Exception('Exceeded upload_max_filesize');
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                throw new Exception('Exceeded MAX_FILE_SIZE');
            case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
                throw new Exception('Incomplete file uploaded');
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                throw new Exception('No file uploaded');
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
                throw new Exception('No tmp directory');
            case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
                throw new Exception('Can\'t write data');
            case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
                throw new Exception('Extension error');
        }

        $finfo    = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
        $name     = $_FILES[$upload_key]['name'];
        $tmp_name = $_FILES[$upload_key]['tmp_name'];
        $size     = $_FILES[$upload_key]['size'];

        if ($size > 350000)
            throw new Exception('Exceeded 350KB limit');
        if (!is_uploaded_file($tmp_name))
            throw new Exception('Not an uploaded file');

        $type = $finfo->file($tmp_name);

        if ($type === false)
            throw new Exception('Failed to get MimeType');
        if ($type !== 'image/jpeg; charset=binary')
            throw new Exception('Only JPEG files available');

        $new_name = dirname(__FILE__).'/upload/'.$name;

        if (is_file($new_name))
            throw new Exception("The file {$new_name} already exists");

        if (!move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$new_name))
            throw new Exception('Failed to move uploaded file');

        $msg = "File successfully uploaded as {$new_name}";

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        $msg = 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();

    }

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Uploader</title>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>" method="post">
<div><input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" /></div>
<div>Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploaded_file" type="file" /></div>
<div><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></div>
</form>
<p>
<?php echo $msg.PHP_EOL; ?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Error: Failed to move uploaded file -- this message is showing now

Comment: Wasn't there occurred any warnings?

Comment: According to the Manual: If *filename* is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and `move_uploaded_file()` will return `FALSE`. If *filename* is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some reason, no action will occur, and `move_uploaded_file()` will return *FALSE*. Additionally, a **warning** will be issued.

Comment: [Tue May 14 14:01:51 2013] [error] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phppeAuyA' to '/var/www/JS_Project1/upload/BeFunky_920372_4444811890760_360826068_o.jpeg' in /var/www/JS_Project1/upload.php on line 48

Comment: [Tue May 14 14:04:10 2013] [error] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(/var/www/JS_Project1/upload/BeFunky_920372_4444811890760_360826068_o.jpeg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/JS_Project1/upload.php on line 48

Comment: It seems that the directory `./upload` doesn't exists, or its permission is not `777`.

Comment: This is ANSWER! : failed to open stream: **Permission denied** in /var/www/JS_Project1/upload.php on line 48

Comment: I guess that `./upload` is set its permission as `755`. But it requires `777`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29907/discussion-between-dinoop-nair-and-certain)